# Creating a XYZ plot for random numbers

Tags: android-layout

I am new to Android and I am trying to create an app that takes a set of random coordinates and plots them onto an XYZ graph. So far i have create the random number generator. I tried to use Achartengine but that has not worked out. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit difficult to know where you are going wrong as there is not that much info.
If you are new to Android or Achartengine you could try getting a working graph with the [examples from Achartengines](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/list) download list. Then editing that to make just have your three random points. The instructions on how to use the examples are [here](http://www.achartengine.org/content/goodies.html).